# Consulta com dados relacionados no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando trazer dados dos materiais com os dados dos seus relacionamentos com as tabelas Unidade e TD, mas esse código abaixo não retorna nada, se eu faço sem o Include() ele retorna os dados mas com o relacionamento não traz nenhum resultado. Na classe Material eu tenho as propriedades de navegação para Unidade e TD.

```
    public IEnumerable<Material> Listar(String Nome)
    {
        IEnumerable<Material> materiais = (from x in db.Material
                                           .Include("Unidade")
                                           .Include("TD")
                                           .Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(Nome)) select x).ToList();                               
        return materiais;
    }
```

Codigo SQL gerado pelo Entity:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[CodTron] AS [CodTron], 
[Extent1].[RefTron] AS [RefTron], 
[Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome], 
[Extent1].[UnidadeID] AS [UnidadeID], 
[Extent1].[TDID] AS [TDID], 
[Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
[Extent2].[CodTron] AS [CodTron1], 
[Extent2].[Referencia] AS [Referencia], 
[Extent2].[Descricao] AS [Descricao], 
[Extent2].[Simbolo] AS [Simbolo], 
[Extent3].[ID] AS [ID2], 
[Extent3].[Numero] AS [Numero], 
[Extent3].[Descricao] AS [Descricao1], 
[Extent3].[RefTron] AS [RefTron1]
FROM   [dbo].[Material] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Unidade] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UnidadeID] = [Extent2].[ID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TD] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[TDID] = [Extent3].[ID]
WHERE [Extent1].[Nome] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~'
```

Comment: Quais são os dados já inclusos no banco? Qual `String` você está utilizando para a pesquisa?

Comment: Tenho mais de 600 itens no banco na table Material, estou pesquisando um material que tenho certeza que tem no banco, e como eu disse, quando eu tiro o Include ele traz o resultado corretamente mas sem os dados de TD e Unidade.

Comment: Experimente pegar a consulta gerada fazendo o seguinte: `var stringTeste = (from x in db.Material.Include("Unidade").Include("TD").Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(Nome))).ToString()`. Coloque a `String` gerada no SQL Server Management Studio e veja o que acontece.

Comment: a String da erro, Must declare scalar variable @p__linq__0, veja, atualizei a minha pergunta e postei o codigo SQL gerado.

Comment: Mesmo se eu substituir o parâmentro por um nome de material o SQL Server não me retorna nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diego e Cigano Morrison, encontrei o erro: era um erro na tabela de `Unidade` no banco de dados. Por padrão o Entity Framework vai fazer os Inner Joins pelas propriedades de navegação, no meu caso o `UnidadeID` e o `TDID`, mas eu preciso que a associação seja feita por outro campo da tabela, o `CodTron`, ou seja, a comparação correta é `Unidade.MaterialID = Unidade.CodTron` e na tabela de TD a compração seria `Materia.TDID = TD.CodTron`, isso acontece no meu caso por que os dados dessas duas tabelas vem de outro sistema e são importados via `Integration Services`, e as associações devem ser feitas pelos códigos que estão no outro sistema.

Por causa desse erro ele acaba não fazendo nenhuma referência a dados na *table* de `Unidade` por isso não traz os dados. Depois que o @Cigano falou para colocar o código gerado pelo Entity no Management Studio eu vi que mesmo substituindo o parâmetro pelo nome do material ele não trazia os dados, então comecei a investigar mais o banco e achei o erro.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia marcar esta resposta como aceita, descrevendo melhor este erro, em benefício dessa comunidade? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Só posso marcar minha própria resposta dentro de 2 dias, se achar apropriada marque por favor.

Comment: @user36700112 Ok, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso:

```
IEnumerable<Material> materiais = db.Material
                                       .Include(u=>u.Unidade)
                                       .Include(t=>t.TD)
                                       .Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(Nome)).ToList();
```

Não esqueça de importar a referência:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: Diego, continua do mesmo jeito, não retorna nenhuma informação.

Comment: @user3670112, tente agora, não é necessário o from. Adicione na pergunta as classes Material, Unidade e TD, para exemplificar seu ambiente.

Comment: Ainda continua o problema Diego.